# jquery, checkbox select all not enabling the events on other checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html

I have a select all checkbox.

```
<br>DK Filtering :
    <input type="checkbox" name="asdf" id="asdf" value="A" CHECKED>A
    <input type="checkbox" name="asdf" id="asdf" value="B">B
    <input type="checkbox" name="asdf" id="asdf" value="C_EVAL">CEval
    <input type="checkbox" name="asdf" id="asdf" value="D_EVAL">DEval
    <input type="checkbox" name="dkfilterall" id="dkfilterall" value="YES">Select All
<br>
    <script>
    \$("input[name=dkfilterall]").click(function() {
       if (\$('input[name=dkfilterall]').is(':checked')== true)
       {
            \$('input[name=asdf]').attr('checked', true);
       }
       if (\$('input[name=dkfilterall]').is(':checked')== false)
       {
            \$('input[name=asdf]').attr('checked', false);
       }
    });            
    </script>
```

Somewhere later, I have this function:

```
<script>
        \$("input[name=asdf]").live(function() {

...
</script>
```

I thought the act of checking the individual checkboxes through select all checkbox would trigger the function of the individual checkboxes but this isn't happening.

What do I need to do to correct this?

thanks
Gordon

Comment: What's going on with the use of `\$` instead of `$`?

Comment: i am doing the programming in perl ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you check the boxes, you need to call their corresponding `.change()` function to trigger them:

```
$('input[name=asdf]').attr('checked', true).change();
```

Here's a (simplified) [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/KR8Xc/) that checks all the boxes and then calls their `change()` function.

Comment: i have only a click function but no change. how can i make it work for a click function

Comment: change your click function to a change function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify an event type for live, so `.live('click', function() {});`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are checking if the checkboxes are already checked, you can just call the click event on them and it will trigger the functions.  i.e.

```
$("input[name=dkfilterall]").click(function() {
       if ($('input[name=dkfilterall]').is(':checked')== true)
       {
            $('input[name=asdf]').click();
       }
       if ($('input[name=dkfilterall]').is(':checked')== false)
       {
            $('input[name=asdf]').click();
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to trigger some event (click, change) after you manually checked a checkbox, you must call `trigger` method to the object:

   ```
   $('input[name=asdf]').attr('checked', true)
      .trigger("change"); // <-- this code added
   ```
2. In your example you trying to use `live` method that used to bind a trigger for static and dynamically created elements. To use it correctly the code must be like this:

   ```
   $("input[name=asdf]").live("click", function() {
      // Live handler called.
   });
   ```

See more information on [official jquery site](http://api.jquery.com/live/).